# Rails - Security best practices for production server passwords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, security, passwords

Should I be checking in the production server database password into git? What is the best practice here? Should I make this password different than the root linux password? Any other security best practices from an os / password standpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't store production passwords in git, no matter whether you use github or your own git server. It is just another potential point of failure/vulnerability. If you already have done this, you should remove the files containing them (also from the history) - there are numerous SO questions how to do this. If you already pushed these files to a remote server, you should change the passwords.

As for a best practice, you could use the dotenv gem (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)
In this way you can extract all sensitive data for production in rails environment variables in one single file .env.production. This file should exist only on the production server and should be added to your git ignore file just to be sure.

Dotenv allows you to set variables for each environment in a file called .env.[development|production|test|whatever]. You can push your non-sensitive files/data for development, test, etc. but ignore the important ones. You can access these variables with `ENV['MY_ENV_VARIABLE']`. (In each of your .env files you will then have a line `MY_ENV_VARIABLE="some super secret password"`)

One downside with this approach is that you have to make sure you edit the .env.production file every time you add a new sensitive data/field to your app on the server.